# Alternate to Vieta's formula to find $a,b,c,d$ in this question.

Tags: roots

**Question :**

> Roots of the equation $$x^{4}+2 x^{3}-5x^{2}+7x+10=0$$ are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ and that of $x^{4}+a x^{3}+b x^{2}+c x+d=0$ be
> $\alpha+\beta+\gamma, \alpha+\beta+\delta, \alpha+\gamma+\delta ; \beta+\gamma+\delta,$ then find the value of
> $a+b-c-d$.

*What I tried:*

By applying Vieta's formula(In 2nd Equation):
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\alpha+\beta+\delta+\alpha+\gamma+\delta+\beta+\gamma+\delta=-a$$
$$=3(\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta)=-a \tag1\label{eq1} $$
and By applying in Vieta's formula in 1st equation we get:
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=-2 \tag2\label{eq2}$$
From $\eqref{eq1}$ and $\eqref{eq2}$:

$$a=6$$
In similar way, I would find $b,c,d $ which is a very tedious and time consuming method(and it's not guaranteed that answer will come).

Is there any other way?

**Hint**
(Not complete answer)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the roots of the second polynomial $p(x)$ are $-2-\alpha$, $-2-\beta$,...so if we write it in a factor form we have $$p(x)=(x+2+\alpha)(x+2+\beta)...$$ so $$p(-x-2)= (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)...=q(x)$$ where $q(x)$ is a starting polynomial. So $$p(x) = q(-x-2)=...$$

Answer (score 3):

Idea: Perform a change of roots.

More specifically, if $x_i$ are the roots to the original equation, we want $y_i = f(x_i)$ to be the roots to the new equation. What is $f(x)$?

> **Hint:**  Like you stated, $\alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta = -2$

> $f(x) = -2 - x$

$$x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cd + d = f(x) ^ 4 + 2f(x) ^3  - 5f(x)^2 + 7 f(x) + 10  .$$

Using the transformation, expanding the expression gives us

> $ x^4 + 6x^3 + 7x^2 - 19x - 24 $

Comment: Can you explain how you got that equality..? with the quartic poly nomial and polynomial in f(x)?

Comment: @Buraian Does Aqua's answer shed more light? If not, please elaborate on what part you do not understand.